# can not install scrapy on my mac

Tags: python, scrapy

I have tried to install scrapy on my mac(10.12.3)but failed. In fact, I can import scrapy in pycharm and there is no error, however, when I try to use in my terminal, error happened.

```
loohazeMacBook-Pro:~ loohaze$ scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Scrapy==1.3.2', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "/Users/loohaze/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 121, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
  File "/Users/loohaze/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 45, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
  File "/Users/loohaze/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 28, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "/Users/loohaze/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 19, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
  File "/Users/loohaze/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/loohaze/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scrapy/commands/version.py", line 6, in <module>
    import OpenSSL
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 12, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib

ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_openssl)
```

I'm new to python, please help! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do:
    xcode-select --install

There are known issues in the installation guide of scrapy - https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html